# Check if URL is a downloadable file in Java

Tags: java, url

I need to check an URL to verify if this URL directly downloads a file of any type.

Currently, I do this:

```java
  URL url = new URL(uri);

  HttpURLConnection huc = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
  huc.setRequestMethod("HEAD");

  int responseCode = huc.getResponseCode();

  //URL url = new URL(uri);
  URLConnection connection = url.openConnection();
  InputStream in = connection.getInputStream();

  try (InputStream is = in; BufferedInputStream bis = new BufferedInputStream(is);) {
    AutoDetectParser parser = new AutoDetectParser();
    Detector detector = parser.getDetector();
    Metadata md = new Metadata();
    md.add(Metadata.RESOURCE_NAME_KEY, FilenameUtils.getBaseName(url.getPath()));
    MediaType mediaType = detector.detect(bis, md);
    String mime = mediaType.toString();

    if (type.equals(IMAGE_HEADER) && mime.contains(IMAGE_HEADER.toLowerCase())) {
      return true;
    } else if (type.equals(IMAGE_HEADER) && !mime.contains(IMAGE_HEADER.toLowerCase())) {
      return false;
    } else if (type.equals(DOCUMENT_HEADER) && mime.contains("pdf")) {
      return true;
    } else if (type.equals(DOCUMENT_HEADER) && !mime.contains("pdf")) {
      return false;
    } else
      return false;
  }
}
```

However, this downloads the file and I have to check this up to 1000 times, so, what I need is to check if the URL has a downloadable file without download the binaries. Is this possible?

Also, if it is possible to check its MIME type without download the whole file, would be perfect.

Comment: Technically no, you have to download the whole file to check it.  You might be able to just open a connection, or read the first byte, and call that "good enough" as a check.  But the idea that a URL should be "checked" is pretty suspect, so I think your requirement is the problem, not the lack of a good "check" method.

Comment: You could use a HEAD request to get the headers only, and check the content-type and maybe the content-disposition headers, but that assumes that those values are 1) populated and 2) have suitable values, which is not necessarily the case.

Comment: How can I do that? @MarkRotteveel

Comment: See [`setRequestMethod`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/net/HttpURLConnection.html#setRequestMethod(java.lang.String)) and [`getHeaderFields`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/net/URLConnection.html#getHeaderFields()). Also consider using a more evolved and future-rich HTTP client library.

Comment: That's not your actual code is it? I don't see a variable `type` declared…